# Connection to Redis failed - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, cache, redis

I am getting this error while browsing to both front and backend of my Magento store :

```
Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (111) Connection refused

Trace:
    public_html/lib/Credis/Client.php(439): Credis_Client->connect()
    public_html/lib/Credis/Client.php(725): Credis_Client->connect()
    public_html/lib/Credis/Client.php(599): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
    public_html/lib/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(135): Credis_Client->select(1)
    public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
    public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
    public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(136): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
    public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1357): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
    public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
    public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(412): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
    public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
    public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
    public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    {main}

Error log record number: 1349533104724
```

Answer (score 0):

You must start the redis-server or else change the setting for auto start.